# Another fixing the "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" error

Tags: html, css, file-not-found

I'm having trouble getting my CSS to load in any browser using the "Copy Path" option in VSCode. Everything shows up fine when using the preview mode within VS but when trying to copy the path and getting it to load in Chrome or Edge none of the style shows up.

Here is the link tag in my HTML:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Course 4/portfolioproject/styles.css">
```

and a screenshot: [so you can see the dev tools a bit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOAm6.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOAm6.jpg)
Not sure if something got corrupted or what but any help would be great.

I've tried making an entirely new css file and just copying the code over but that didn't work. I double checked that my paths were correct. I also cleared my cache history in google chrome for all time.

Answer (score 1):

bro, I think this is a bug, this problem happen to me also in something.

when we copy the path, then we see some style are not shown up. (this is a bug).

but if you open through the live server then, everything will shown perfectly.

check it in the live server through VS code, I think this will work....